# Change Laravel Web Tinker Public Files Directory - Prevent 403 Error on Saving

Tags: laravel, tinker

I love [this little library](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-web-tinker) - so helpful.

However, it places some of its css and js files in a **vendor** folder inside the **public** directory of Laravel.  I've got a `Vendor` class and paths in several apps and so, when saving a new `Vendor`, it redirects 403 Forbidden due to the conflicted **vendor** folder in the **public** directory.

I can't go back and refactor just for this to work, much as I like it.

It comes with a publishable config file, but I don't see an option to change the path to these files to a location outside the **vendor** folder.  I don't want to make changes to the Spatie files, as this would just be overwritten upon next update.

Am I missing something easy here?  Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently a config setting that allows you to control this.

The line causing you grief is here - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-web-tinker/blob/master/src/WebTinkerServiceProvider.php#L29. It publishes the compiled assets, as you say, into the public/vendor folder.

If you do not want to refactor your existing work, you can:

1. PR/fork a change to add this as a config setting
2. Manually change it on your end (although this could easily break if you republsihed the assets ever

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help @James.